# Custom method create in ModelViewset Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello guys and girls,

Just having a little issue with Django Rest Framework : let's say I have a Book class :

models.py

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length = 50, blank=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class BooksSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ['id', 'title']
```

And now I want to allow the create method only until I have 30 books in database.

This is the kind of code I have until now but it isn't working so far, how would you recommend me to proceed ?
I can override the create method from the ModelViewSet class right ?

views.py

```
class BooksViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Books.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer

    def create(self, serializer):
        number_of_books = queryset.count()
        if number of book < 30:
            serializer.save()
        else:
            response = {'message': 'You can't create more than 30 values'}
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to override and validate the request

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class BooksViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Books.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book_count = self.get_queryset().count()
        if book_count >= 30:
            return Response(
                {"message": "Max book create limit exceeded"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

what about super charging `save()` method of **Books model**?

The idea here is to change the save behaviour of Books model as required, for instance, limiting the amount of books in DB at 30

```py
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length = 50, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Books.objects.all().count() < 30:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise TypeError("No more then 30 books, merci pour le libraire")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods